# How to simplify macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here and to the world of VBA. 
I've been asked to create a spreadsheet which a user can enter a task number of a job they have been given, from this auto populate other columns with data from a master list, and then when they change the status of the job the row changes colour. 
I know that this is easy to do using the vlookup function as a formula in each cell and conditional formatting. 
I have searched the web and have found differnt macros that can do the job, but some of them take far to long to find a match, the master task list can contain upto 3000 items. 
So I've very crudely cobbled together something that works and quickly.
I was wondering how I can clean these macros up as I'm sure the way I've done it will cause problems in the future or if there is a better way to do the job.

Also as a secoundry question is there any way to get a message box to pop up if the number the user enters doesn't match anything on the master list.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim Status As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B700") 'Range Looking for Change
Set Status = Range("K1:K700")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

     Dim SourceLastRow As Long
        Dim OutputLastRow As Long
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim outputSheet As Worksheet


            Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Task List")
            Set outputSheet = Worksheets("2016")

    'Determine last row of Task List
            With sourceSheet
                SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End With

            With outputSheet
 'Determine last row in col B
            OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 'Put formula in relevant cell
            .Range("F2:F" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Task List'!$A$2:$D$" & SourceLastRow & ",2,0)"
            End With

   With outputSheet
                 OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                 .Range("H2:H" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Task List'!$A$2:$D$" & SourceLastRow & ",3,0)"
            End With

            With outputSheet
                 OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                 .Range("G2:G" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(B2,'Task List'!$A$2:$D$" & SourceLastRow & ",4,0)"
            End With

End If





If Not Application.Intersect(Status, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    Dim n As Long
        iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For n = iLastRow To 1 Step -1

                If Cells(n, "K").Value = "Closed" Then
                    Rows(n).Interior.Color = RGB(57, 255, 20) 
                End If

                If Cells(n, "K").Value = "Bond" Then
                    Rows(n).Interior.Color = RGB(249, 255, 1) 
                End If

                If Cells(n, "K").Value = "Eng Bond" Then
                    Rows(n).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0) 
                End If


                If Cells(n, "K").Value = "Fail" Then
                    Rows(n).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 1, 1) 
                End If

                If Cells(n, "K").Value = "" Then
                    Rows(n).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                End If


        Next n

End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems more fit to [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: To get a message box to pop up, simply write `MsgBox "This is my message box"` For additional details, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Replace your multiple `Ifs` in `If Cells(n, "K").Value = "Closed" Then` , with `Select Case`. E.g `Select Case Cells(n, "K").Value` , then each line will be `Case "Closed"`, etc...